# Trigger select from an anchor

Tags: angular, angular-material

This is something really simple what I need to do is pass a variable or something to my method.
**the problem with this code is** that when the onPickupClock is triggered it opens the first component, that is the `<md-select name="price">` and not the component itself

**My question is:**
How can I set it to open the component itself, the `<md-select name="clocktime">`?

this is the [angular material select doc](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview) if you want to take a look

**home.component.ts**

```
import { MdSelect } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
....
})

export class HomeComponent {

  @ViewChild(MdSelect) dp: MdSelect;

  onPickupClock(e) {
   this.dp.toggle(e);
  }
}
```

**home.component.html**

```
 <md-select [(ngModel)]="selectedPrice" floatPlaceholder="never" name="price">
    <md-option *ngFor="let price of prices" [value]="price.value">
     {{price.viewValue}}
    </md-option>
 </md-select>
...
<div>
 <a (click)="onPickupClock()">
   <img src="/assets/home/xxx.png">
 </a>
</div>

 <md-select [(ngModel)]="selectedClockPickup" floatPlaceholder="never" name="clocktime">

  <md-option *ngFor="let clocktime of clocktimes [value]="clocktime.value">
   {{clocktime.viewValue}}
  </md-option>

 </md-select>
```

Comment: When you click the link you want to get the selected value from the `md-select name="clocktime"` ?

Comment: yes, I get a MouseEvent object  and  the srcElement is the  img that I'm clicking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option #1**: **Use ViewChild properties**

Define your selects with template reference variables

```
<md-select #priceSelect>
</md-select>

<md-select #clockTimeSelect>
</md-select>
```

Update `home.component.ts` and create two [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) properties on your component.

```
  @ViewChild('priceSelect') priceSelect: MdSelect;
  @ViewChild('clockTimeSelect') clockTimeSelect: MdSelect;
```

Notice the selectors for the ViewChild decorator are template reference variables you used in the template. This gives you direct access the components.

```
  onPickupClock() {
    this.clockTimeSelect.toggle();
  }
```

**Option #2**: **Pass Template reference directly to calling function**

Pass the template reference variable to the click event.

First give your `md-select` a local template variable name, called #clockTimeSelect

```
 <md-select #clockTimeSelect [(ngModel)]="selectedClockPickup" floatPlaceholder="never" name="clocktime">
  <md-option *ngFor="let clocktime of clocktimes [value]="clocktime.value">
   {{clocktime.viewValue}}
  </md-option>
 </md-select>
```

Then update your click to pass the template reference variable.

```
 <a (click)="onPickupClock(clockTimeSelect)">
   <img src="/assets/home/xxx.png">
 </a>
```

Update the component function to receive a MdSelect

```
onPickupClock(mdSelect: MdSelect) {
  mdSelect.toggle();
}
```

Comment: Aaaaamazing!!...it not just work it helps me to understand more about it... ...I have too many things to learn gosh... also I 'd like to ask you something... if you go to https://material.angular.io/components/select/api in the directive section let's say that you want to use the selected property how would you used? I guess in the <md-option> but how do you set up?would br something like <md-option [selected] > ? I just want to understand how to use the APIand how about those properties with @Input() @output()..Thanks for everything

Comment: I believe you just need to bind the `md-select` with ng-Model, and you can set the value of the option based off that value in the component. Make sure you accept the answer